# Android Setting Background

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to change the background of my first app to a png I have. I put the png in a newly created folder called "drawable." When I go to browse my "drawable" I can't see it's "children" or files. The only error of sorts that it gives me is "You must... rce item" anyone run into this? Android API 7 by the way.

Comment: For anyone that see's this in the future. I restarted eclipse and it gave me the drop down arrow to see it's files.

Comment: I think just an F5 (refresh) on /res would do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the png in /res/drawable and then do a clean on your project in eclipse to force the .R class for your app to be recreated. You might also need to do an f5/refresh in eclipse on the project to get it to see that you have added a file in filesystem to /res/drawable.